# Mirror mesh with hair particles

Tags: mesh, particles, mirror, mirror-modifier

I tried mirroring a mesh with hair particles, but only the original works properly. I tried moving the *Mirror* modifier to the top of the modifier list, which still doesn't work. Any solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you apply the mirror it will work for you.

To do this you have to press on little arrow and apply the modifier.

[image]

I hope it is of use to you.

Comment: nope. Still, it won't work

Comment: if you share your project with https://blend-exchange.com/ it will be easier to help you